# ARIMA and SARIMA state space form

Tags: time-series, arima, seasonality, kalman-filter, state-space-models

I need to write down a program that place ARIMA(p,d,q) and SARIMA models in state space form, however I cannot figure out the composition of the system matrices.
In the book of Koopman (pag. 54) the matrices for a general ARMA(p,q) model are shown, however I cannot figure out how to extend the results when differencing or seasonal differencing is introduced.
Any help?

Comment: Two (mathematically) equivalent solutions are often used, see https://www.stat.purdue.edu/~chong/stat520/ps/statespace.pdf. You need to explicit the "left hand side polynomial" $\varphi(B)$. Of course many software do this automatically.